# Vaadin internationalization of OptionGroup labels with enums

Tags: java, internationalization, vaadin

I am currently creating a web application using Vaadin 7. My problem is that I have an OptionGroup that I want to provide labels for. The items of the OptionGroup are enum values. I want those item labels to be internationalized with java resourcebundle, so every enum value has a key given as a constructor parameter. A bean uses this key to get the translation for the current locale (well... the bean holds the current locale, so I need it even if I use the Messages class itself in the enum to get the translation).

My problem now is, that I can't find a way to use this translation as a label for the OptionGroup, because I can either use toString() (which is not possible because I need the translation bean to be passed as a parameter) or a getDisplayString(param) method (which accepts the bean of course, but can't be called by OptionGroup).

As an example see the following snippet

Enum:

```
public enum Gender {

    MALE(Messages.MALE), FEMALE(Messages.FEMALE);

    private String i18nKey;

    private Gender(String i18nKey) {
        this.i18nKey = i18nKey;
    }

    public String getDisplayString(TranslationBean bean) {
        return bean.getString(i18nKey);
    }
}
```

Creating the option group

```
OptionGroup optionGroup = new OptionGroup();
optionGroup.addItems(Gender.values());
optionGroup.setItemCaptionMode(ItemCaptionMode.PROPERTY);
optionGroup.setItemCaptionPropertyId("displayString"); //hoped this would call the corresponding method but it doesn't
```

I guess there must be a way to do this. I would prefere to keep a bean doing the translation, but if there is no other way to do it, I could change this up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will have to wrap your enum in a real class, where you can pass the translation bean as a argument in the constructor

Comment: Your could also use the explicit mode and set the caption with `for (gender : Gender.values()) optionGroup.setItemCaption(gender, gender.getDisplayString(bean));`

Comment: @A.Meier thats the way I did it now. As I have more enums I hoped to find another way to do it, but it seems like there is none